# Period of repeating decimal

Tags: number-representation

I came across of a 6-grader school problem to perform the following division 357.56/19. Pupils in the school understand that both numbers are numerically exact.

I would like to introduce Mathematica to children. How can I explain them how to solve this problem in MA? How can one find the period of this number?

Please, be pedagogical in you answers. I came up with

```
N[35756/1900, 100]
```

for the first question. But I still do not know a simple answer for the second question.

Comment: They expect sixth graders to cough up a decimal where the repeating segment has length 18? They must seriously dislike sixth graders.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Yes, this is a real world case in Germany :)

Comment: And what do they do to seventh graders? Eat them?

Comment: No, that's what they do to ate graders

Comment: Is an answer based on MultiplicativeOrder out of bounds? Assuming the denominator is relatively prime to 10, the length is just `MultiplicativeOrder[10, denominator]`

Comment: @CarlWoll I have never thought of this. Is there way to make it work for arbitrary denominators?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As written on [MathWorld](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/RepeatingDecimal.html), you can use `RealDigits`.

```
r = 35756/1900;
RealDigits[r][[1, -1]]
(* {8,9,4,7,3,6,8,4,2,1,0,5,2,6,3,1,5,7} *)

Length[%]
(* 18 *)
```

Pedagocially, you should probably – as proposed by @MichaelE2 – present this in several steps. First defining the number, then observing the structure of `RealDigits[r]`, then extracting parts of the results (also possible with `First` and `Last`), then counting the numbers ...

Comment: And the period is? Notice, however, that `[[1, -1]]´syntax might be hard to understand for children.

Comment: @yarchik: `Dimensions[RealDigits[r][[1, -1]]][[1]]` results in `18`.

Comment: @yarchik I think you would have to explain the output syntax of `RealDigits[r]`. While clear (in a technical sense), the notation is new and unfamiliar and has lots of braces that mean nothing to a sixth-grade newbie.  The `[[-1, 1]]` seems unnecessary, strictly speaking.  They could copy and paste the answer from the output, if they needed to put the answer somewhere.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Yes, this is probably the way to go.

Comment: @yarchik, sorry, I somehow forgot about the period.

Answer (score 2):

To illustrate [`NestWhileList`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NestWhileList.html)

```
f[x_, y_] :=
 Module[{nst = 
    NestWhileList[QuotientRemainder[10 #, y][[2]] &, 
     QuotientRemainder[x, y][[2]], Unequal, All, Infinity]},
  #2 - #1 & @@ (Flatten@Position[nst, nst[[-1]]])]
```

`f[35756, 1900]` yields 18